# Regex replace multiple new lines

Tags: c#, regex

In C# how do i specify regex to replace multiple groups. For example i would like to replace more than one instance of either `\r\n` or `\r\r` with a environment newline. I logically wrote this regex , but i know it is wrong. Please correct and explain how it works.

```
System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Replace(task.Message, @"(\r\n){2,}(\r\r){2,}", System.Environment.NewLine);
```

Input text

```
Stackoverflow

StackExchange

User Experience
```

Where each line may be separated either by `\r\n` or `\r\r`. Expected outcome after regex replace is below

```
Stackoverflow    
StackExchange    
User Experience
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The point is that your regex matches *sequences* of `\r\n` (2 or more) and then 2 or more *sequences* of `\r\r`. You need

```
[\r\n]+
```

Or `[\r\n]{2,}` if you need to only match 2 or more occurrences of `\r` or `\n`.

If you need to exactly match 2 or more common line break types (`\r\n` in Windows, `\n` in Unix/Linux and `\r` on Mac OS), use

```
(?:\r?\n|\r){2,}
```

Comment: Work's flawlessly. Guess regex should always be on my learning list